# Counting integers in the Thue-Morse sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let's call the infinite Thue-Morse sequence $T$. Define $\delta (n)$ to be $1$ if the binary representation of $n$ appears in $T$ and $0$ otherwise. Let $$F(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\delta(i)$$

$\delta(7)=0$ , $\delta(300)=1$

$F(100)=32$ , $F(1000)=72$

According to wikipedia and MathWorld, an integer that appears in $T$ must have its binary representation [overlapfree](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OverlapfreeWord.html). However, not all overlapfree representations will appear, for example $54=110110_2$ does not appear. I found a [paper](https://oeis.org/A007777/a007777.pdf) describing an algorithm to count overlapfree words of a given length, but it doesn't readily apply here because not all words represent a valid integer, and because I want to find $F(n)$ for arbitrary integer $n$, and not just for $n=2^k-1$ for some integer $k$.

Can the above algorithm be adjusted somehow? Is there any way to evaluate $F(n)$ exactly? Is there any asymptotic approximation for $F(n)$?

Comment: *"... an integer will appear in $T$ if it's binary representation is overlapfree."* Consider $54=(110110)_2.$ Isn't $110110$ overlap-free without appearing in $T?$

Comment: @r.e.s. Yes, it seems correct. Then I believe every integer that appears is overlapfree, but not overlapfree integers appear. Thank you. Then is there a better characterization of the integers that do appear?